# Martin vs Dennis - Round 1: Who has more rep?

Tags: code-golf, internet, stack-exchange-api

I know there have been a lot of challenges about "the two best code-golfers in the world", but this one is a bit more unique, being *Round 1* in a series of (future) challenges involving the two of them.

---

Your task is to write a program or function that returns two different non-whitespace ASCII strings, corresponding to the one who has more reputation at the moment the program is ran, between [Dennis ♦](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) and [Martin Ender ♦](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender). The tricky part is that you must output the exact string ***"tie"*** in case the reputation is identical (not likely), and the two *different non-whitespace ASCII strings* mentioned above should be different than *"tie"* *****.

No input can be taken, such as usernames or user ids. As usual, URL shorteners are forbidden, and so are the common loopholes.

### Examples:

```
Let the chosen string for Dennis be "D" and the chosen one for Martin Ender be "M" (should be specified)

If Dennis' rep > Martin Ender's rep => D
If it's the other way around => M
If it's a tie => tie
```

---

> **IMPORTANT!** Voting on posts by Dennis & Martin for the  sole purpose of affecting a tie in order to test the solutions below constitutes targeted voting which is forbidden across the Stack Exchange network. If you want to test that a solution properly outputs `tie` then change the IDs in it to those of 2 users you know to be tied. See [this Meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12334/58974) for more details.

<sup>**I think no one would have used that, anyway*</sup>

Comment: "... the two best code-golfers in the world ..." [citation-needed]

Comment: Can we assume that they will always be #1 and #2 in this community?

Comment: Yes, you can, as long as they are the #1 and #2, then you update the answer :)

Comment: A friendly reminder: targeted voting is forbidden on the entire Stack Exchange network. Voting on Martin's and my posts just to test submissions to this challenge is *not* allowed.

Comment: @Dennis we all know that, but thanks for the reminder. It was just a joke, don't take it seriously

Comment: The thing is, if you look at Martin's and my own rep history over the last couple of days, it seems like a handful of users *did* need a reminder.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder, feel free to edit/move that notice I just edited in.

Comment: @Shaggy It's great that you have added that note. Hopefully, the users involved will stop doing that

Comment: Sorry for my grammar, I meant to say *Although one of the answers has been accepted, it would be nice to see some more interesting solutions*

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "interesting"? :)

Comment: Any new smart answer that uses a different approach than the current ones

Comment: So ... when's round 2?!

Comment: @Shaggy it's coming soon. I have some minor things to change till I post it.

Comment: To @MartinEnder at the top, citations are unneeded for facts that are common knowledge.

Comment: still waiting for round 2

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/), <s>65</s> 64 bytes

#### Code:

```
•в=6{•5ôvy’ƒËŠˆ.Â‚‹º.ŒŒ/†š/ÿ’.w’„Ö="Âˆ"’¡1èт£þ}})ZQā*O<“D M·‡“#è
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding.

#### Explanation:

`•в=6{•` converts the number `в=6{` from base 255 to base 10, resulting in [1201208478](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@/@oYdGFTbZm1UD6/38A). The first half being the ID of Dennis (12012) and the second half being the ID of Martin (8478). Split into pieces of 5 using `5ô` to get the following array:

```
['12012', '08478']
```

Luckily, we can leave the leading zero from Martin's ID, since [this will still work](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/08478) (check the link before clicking to see the leading zero).

We now loop through this array using `vy` and construct the following string from this 05AB1E code:

```
’ƒËŠˆ.Â‚‹º.ŒŒ/†š/ÿ’  -->  codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/ÿ
```

Whereas `ÿ` is the current element of the iterator (using string interpolation) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#ATAAz///MTIwMTIg4oCZxpLDi8Wgy4Yuw4LigJrigLnCui7FksWSL@KAoMWhL8O/4oCZ//8)

After constructing the link, `.w` reads all data from the link, resulting into a huge amount of text. To scrape the reputation from this, we need to split on the string `title="reputation"`. Or in a more compressed version: [`’„Ö="Âˆ"’`](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@/@oYeajhnmHp9kqHW463aYE5P7/DwA). Split on this piece of string (with `¡`) and get the second element (with `1è`) and keep the first **100 characters** (with `т£`).

Now, our scraped text looks a bit like this:

```
>
        139,883 <span class="label-uppercase">reputation</span>
   </div>
   
<div class="ba
```

This part is easy, we just remove anything **but digits** to remain the reputation number, for which we have a builtin (`þ`). We end the loop and wrap everything into an array `}})`.

Finally, we can go on to processing the reputation numbers:

```
ZQā*O<“D M·‡“#è   -   On stack: an array in the format [Dennis rep, Martin rep]

Z                 # Get the maximum of the array
 Q                # Check for equality with the array
  ā*              # Multiply by it's index (1-indexed)
    O<            # Sum and decrement by 1
      “D M·‡“#    # Push the array ['D', 'M', 'tie']
              è   # Get the element on the index of the sum
```

Which results in either `D`, `M` or `tie`.

Comment: I didn't know that 05AB1E can access internet APIs, this answer kind surprises me => +1

Comment: I always like how you and others come up with ways to get a certain number. :) +1 Btw, is the part "_second element (with `1è) and keep the first **100 characters** (with т£`._" supposed to be completely in code-blocks, or should it be "_second element (with `1è`) and keep the first **100 characters** (with `т£`)._" instead? I guess a typo, but if it's supposed to be like this I'm confused..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Huh, I have no idea how that happened, but it's fixed now. Thanks for the heads up! :)

Comment: it seems incorrect (I don't know how to correct this kind of code, sorry), `Dennis: 140,033`; `Martin: 140,003`, but I tried your code here https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@/@oYdGFTbZm1UDa9PCWsspHDTOPTTrcfXTB6Ta9w02PGmY9ath5aJfe0UlHJ@k/alhwdKH@4f1ANXrlQOJRw7zD02yVDjedblMCcg8tNDy84mLTocWH99XWakYFHmnU8rd51DDHRcH30PZHDQuBTOXDK/7/BwA, it yield `tie`. Shouldn't it ouput `D` instead?

Comment: @Eddie `.w` requires web access, which is restricted on TIO (it runs 05AB1E in safe mode). In the offline interpreter, it should work.

Comment: @Adnan Nitpick: TIO no longer runs 05AB1E is safe mode, but the sandbox that runs all user requests cuts off all internet access.

Comment: @Dennis Oh, that's neat! Thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 18):

## PowerShell v3+, <s>147</s> <s>123</s> <s>119</s> <s>103</s> <s>101</s> 96 Bytes

```
$a,$b=irm api.stackexchange.com/users/12012`;8478?site=codegolf|% I*|% r*n;$a-$b|% T*g "D;M;Tie"
```

Saved 24 bytes using true/false output instead of the names.

Saved another 4 by restructuring the final checks.

saved 16 by getting only the reputations of the two users from the request, saves having to use the `|% r*n` more than once, also means we can get rid of like a million brackets, and two useless variables.

-2 thanks to [TessellatingHeckler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/571/tessellatingheckler) - using an escape char instead of two doublequotes for the url, also removed the `@` from the array which was un-needed (oopsie)

used a weird `.ToString` trick I never knew existed until now reccomended by [TessellatingHeckler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/571/tessellatingheckler) -5, and finally below 100.

---

Version which returns names:

```
$a,$b=irm "api.stackexchange.com/users/12012;8478?site=codegolf"|% I*
if(($c=$a|% r*n)-eq($d=$b|% r*n)){"tie"}else{@(($a|% d*),($b|% d*))[$c-lt$d]}
```

this looks pretty messy due to the shortening of parameter names.

anywhere `|% r*n` appears we're getting the `ReputatioN`, and `|% d*` is the `Display_name`

uses `Invoke-RestMethod` (alias `irm`) to query the API, stores the result named `Items` (gotten using `|% I*`), into the two variables `$a` & `$b`, one for each pro golfer's, the `ToString` (`|% T*g`) trick results in one of the values `D`,`M` or `Tie` if the number is odd/even/zero.

Comment: I did not expect powershell to be the shortest. +1

Comment: @Riker Pyth would've presumably been, but it has a horrible bug.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer it's not a legitimate victory but i'll take it. would be nice to see a non-competing pyth answer after the bug is fixed though.

Comment: This wont work in PowerShell 2.0 so i think you need to add a version to your post. Beautiful to look at though.

Comment: @Matt I think the `irm` command was first added in v3 - don't have access to a v3 shell to check sadly, definitely not in v2 though, thanks for that.

Comment: Fine, you win; no way I'm going to beat this now!

Comment: Got a short domain? Put a reverse proxy rewrite on it to shorten that hostname... Tried making a hosts file entry but the SE servers need the host header..

Comment: @ConnorLSW It was that and the `Foreach-Object` syntax you are using.

Comment: So your code is `103! = 9.902900716486180407546715254581773349090165822114492483005280554699... × 10^163` bytes long..? :P

Comment: @totallyhuman You beat me to it ;)

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler check the answer for the last bit, you got it below 100! - never knew `ToString` worked like that with +/- numbers, will remember for future.

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 160 bytes

```python
from requests import*
print cmp(*[get('http://api.stackexchange.com/users/12012;8478?%ssite=codegolf&filter=!9aK21rboZ'%s).text for s in'order=asc&',''])or'tie'
```

Not the shortest Python answer, but the shortest one so far that doesn't make any assumptions.

Prints `1` if Martin has more rep, `-1` if I do.

Answer (score 13):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>167</s> <s>156</s> <s>146</s> <s>144</s> <s>141</s> <s>132</s> 103 bytes

Stupid [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and its stupid, expensive [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) chaining!

Assumes, as currently allowed, that Dennis & Martin will always be the 2 top ranked users. Needs to be run from the root level of `api.stackexchange.com`. Returns  a `Promise` object (as is now [permitted by consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12327/58974)) containing `tie` or the JSON object for whoever has the most rep at the time. If the JSON object isn't considered valid output then add 5 bytes for `.link`.

```js
_=>fetch`users/?site=codegolf`.then(r=>r.json()).then(({items:[j,i]})=>j[r="reputation"]==i[r]?"tie":j)
```

- Saved 11 bytes thanks to [Kevin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) suggesting I return the profile `link` rather than the first letter of the `display_name`, which also provide better future-proofing against them changing their usernames to start with the same letter!
- 5 bytes saved adapting a tip from [kamoroso94](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/57013/kamoroso94) on a another solution of mine.

---

### Try It

```js
f=
_=>fetch`//api.stackexchange.com/users/?site=codegolf`.then(r=>r.json()).then(({items:[j,i]})=>j[r="reputation"]==i[r]?"tie":j)
f().then(console.log)
```

---

### Alternative

If a time comes that Dennis & Martin aren't at the top and we still want to know who has the most rep between them then we'd need the following, at a cost of an additional 10 bytes.

```
_=>fetch`users/12012;8478?site=codegolf`.then(r=>r.json()).then(({items:[j,i]})=>j[r="reputation"]==i[r]?"tie":j)
```

Comment: You can change `.display_name[0]` to `.display_name`, or an even shorter alternative that is still unique for both of them: `.link`. ;) Or just the entire JSON, but I'm not sure if it fits in the alert-popup.

Comment: Thanks, @KevinCruijssen; I had to use an extract of the username as Martin's contains a space, which isn't allowed. Good shout on using `link`, though, I was using a filtered API query to only return the info I needed.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I've dumped whole HTML pages into alert popups when dealing with AJAX returns. It can handle it.

Comment: @Draco18s, `alert`ing a JSON object, though, will just display `[object Object]`.

Comment: @Shaggy True, true, it would.

Answer (score 8):

## Python 3, <s>160</s> <s>157</s> 151 bytes

```
from requests import*
a,b,*c=get('http://api.stackexchange.com/users?site=codegolf').json()['items']
r='reputation'
print(['tie',a['link']][a[r]>b[r]])
```

---

*-3 bytes thanks to @KevinCruijssen*

Prints a link to the user having more reputation

Assumes they are on #1 and #2

---

**Without making any assumptions, Python 2, 157 bytes**:

```
from requests import*
a,b=get('http://api.stackexchange.com/users/8478;12012?site=codegolf').json()['items']
r='reputation'
print['tie',a['link']][a[r]>b[r]]
```

Answer (score 6):

## PHP, 167 Bytes

prints -1 for Dennis , 1 for Martin Ender. tie in case of a tie

```
<?=($b=($t=json_decode(gzdecode(join(file('http://api.stackexchange.com/users/12012;8478?site=codegolf&order=asc'))))->items)[0]->reputation<=>$t[1]->reputation)?:tie;
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python, <s>226</s> <s>225</s> 221 bytes

I feel like this is too long.

```
import requests as r,re
def f(i):d=re.sub('[, ]','',r.get('http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/'+i).text);D=d.index('"reputation">')+14;return int(d[D:d.index('<',D)])
a=f('8478')
b=f('12012')
print([a>b,'tie'][a==b])
```

Prints `"True"` if Martin has more rep than Dennis, `"False"` if Dennis has more rep than Martin, and `"tie"` if they have the same (theoretically. I can't test this :P).

`https` -> `http` for 1 byte thanks to @KevinCruijssen!
`re as r, r.sub` -> `re, re.sub` for 4 bytes thanks to @ovs!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but is it possible to change `https` to `http`? I know PPCG is completely https now, but perhaps it auto-directs to HTTPS when you navigate to HTTP in Python, just as it does in a browser?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Ah yes, I don't know what I was thinking there. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need `re as R`. Just use `import requests as r,re` and `re.sub`

Comment: @ovs Heh, my original approach was different Thanks!

Comment: I think you can use the `cmp` function to save some bytes by replacing the last three lines with something like `print['tie',0,1][cmp(f('8478'),f('12012'))]`

Comment: @Loovjo Thanks, but unfortunately this only works for Python 2, and the `requests` part seems to fail for py2.

Answer (score 4):

## Bash + [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), <strike>140</strike> 133 bytes

```
w3m 'api.stackexchange.com/users/12012;8478?site=codegolf&sort=name'|jq '.items|map(.reputation)|1/(index(min)-index(max))'||echo tie
```

### Formatted and explained

First, we <strike>*curl*</strike> w3m the API <strike>(and use `--compressed`, or short `--com` to un-gzip)</strike>:

```
w3m 'api.stackexchange.com/users/12012;8478?site=codegolf&sort=name'
```

That's some JSON. Notice the order ist stable, not based on reputation. JQ then processes the JSON, which is what it's made for.

```
.items                          # take the items array
| map(.reputation)              # extract only the reputations
| 1 / 
  (index(min)-index(max))       # This checks if the bigger value is first (1) or last (-1) in array
```

We use `1/x` above to generate an division-by-zero error when min==max, so in a tie situation. The `||echo tie` in bash catches that.

*Note that a warning is printed on stderr by JQ in that case, but we consider only stdout the actual result of the program ;)*

Comment: You can use `w3m` instead of `curl --com` to save a few bytes. Also, I think it's worth mentioning that this requires jq 1.5, as jq 1.4 didn't raise an error for division by zero.

Comment: True, thanks for the hint. W3m is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>228</s> <s>223</s> <s>204</s> 199 bytes

I did this on a mobile hotspot so... it's not great... <s>Assumes both of them will always be in the same hundred thousand.</s> Doesn't assume anything now. :D

```python
import urllib as l,re
f=lambda i:int(re.search('n">\s*([\d,]+)',l.urlopen('http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/%d'%i).read()).group(1).replace(',',''))
d,m=f(12012),f(8478)
print[d>m,'Tie'][d==m]
```

Prints `True` if Dennis has more reputation than Martin, `False` otherwise and `Tie` if they are... tied.

Answer (score 1):

### [Stackexchange API Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com), <s>184</s> 180 bytes

Thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen for -4 bytes

```
DECLARE @M int,@D int;SELECT @M=reputation from users where id=8478;SELECT @D=reputation from users where id=12012;IF @D=@M PRINT('tie')ELSE BEGIN;IF @D>@M PRINT(1)ELSE PRINT(2)END
```

Prints 1 for Dennis and 2 for Martin

Since i only [yesterday](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143116/56341) learned about the [SEADE](https://data.stackexchange.com) this should be very beatable.

[Try it here](https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/725157/martin-ender-versus-dennis)

Comment: You can change `'D'` and `'M'` to `0` and `1`.