# Answer to Vote Ratio

Tags: code-golf, internet, stack-exchange-api

*This question is inspired by the fact that I love seeing questions with equal vote and answer counts...*

---

So here's a simple [stack-exchange-api](/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-api) challenge for y'all:

**Challenge:**

Given a `codegolf.stackexchange` question id, output the ratio between the question's votes and number of answers (e.g. `votes/answers`).

**Specifics:**

- You may access the internet, but you may only access `stackexchange.com` and its various sub-domains. You may not use URL shorteners.
- You may take input and give output in any standard format.
- You must output the ratio as a decimal number in base 10, with at least 4 {accurate} digits after the decimal (zeros may be truncated).
- If the question is unanswered, your program may produce undefined behavior.
- You should use the `score` of the question as the vote-count, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229255/what-is-the-score-of-a-post).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), least bytes in each language wins for that language, least bytes overall wins overall.

**Here is a sample program in `Python 3 + requests`:**

```
import requests
import json

id = input("id> ")
url = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" + id + "?site=codegolf"
content = requests.get(url).text
question = json.loads(content)["items"][0]

print(float(question["score"]) / question["answer_count"])
```

Comment: Does the ratio need at least 4 decimal digits after the decinal point even if they are zero? E.g. 41/4= 10.25 or 10.2500

Comment: @pizzapants184 10.25 is fine

Comment: What if the challenge is not answered? Then the ratio would be infinite?

Comment: Do you mean *score* or *total votes* on the question?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder in that case, undefined behavior is okay

Comment: @AdmBorkBork technically `score` (which is displayed as `votes` on the main page)

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>103</s> 102 bytes

Needs to be run from the root level of `api.stackexchange.com`. Returns a `Promise` object containing the result.

```js
n=>fetch(`questions/${n}?site=codegolf`).then(r=>r.json()).then(({items:[j]})=>j.score/j.answer_count)
```

- 1 byte saved thanks to [kamoroso94](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/57013/kamoroso94).

If [requiring that it be run from a specific path is allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13938/58974) then that becomes <s>92</s> 90 bytes.

```js
n=>fetch(n+`?site=codegolf`).then(r=>r.json()).then(({items:[j]})=>j.score/j.answer_count)
```

---

### Try it

Full URL added to enable it to work here.

```js
f=
n=>fetch(`//api.stackexchange.com/questions/${n}?site=codegolf`).then(r=>r.json()).then(({items:[j]})=>j.score/j.answer_count)
onchange=_=>f(+i.value).then(t=>o.innerText=t)
```

```html
<input id=i type=number><pre id=o>
```

Comment: Replace `i=>(j=i.items[0])` with `({items:[j]})=>j` to save a byte.

Comment: Nice trick, thanks, @kamoroso94. I'll have to remember that one.

Answer (score 8):

## [Stratos](https://github.com/okx-code/Stratos), 40 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to Shaggy

```
f"¹⁵s/%²"r"⁷s"@0
{s"answer_⁰"
⁰s"score"/
```

[Try it!](http://okx.sh/stratos/?code=f%22%C2%B9%E2%81%B5s%2F%25%C2%B2%22r%22%E2%81%B7s%22%400%0A%7Bs%22answer_%E2%81%B0%22%0A%E2%81%B0s%22score%22%2F&input=143083)

Stratos specialises in [stack-exchange-api](/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-api) questions.

Explanation:

The code decompresses to the following:

```
f"api.stackexchange.com/questions/%?site=codegolf"r"items"@0
{s"answer_count"
⁰s"score"/
```

Starting from the first line, Stratos evaluates the dyads from right to left.

`f"api.stackexchange.com/questions/%?site=codegolf"r"items"@0` means "evaluate the dyad `@` with the left-hand argument `f"api.stackexchange.com/questions/%?site=codegolf"r"items"` and the right-hand argument `0`. `@` gets the *nth* element of a JSON array.

To evaluate `f"api.stackexchange.com/questions/%?site=codegolf"r"items"`, we will next evaluate the dyad `r` with the left-hand argument `f"api.stackexchange.com/questions/%?site=codegolf"` and the right-hand argument `"items"`. `r` gets the JSON array with the specified name.

Next, we will need to evaluate `f"api.stackexchange.com/questions/%?site=codegolf"`. First, `%` is replaced with the input. `f` means "get the contents of this URL".

Now, we can move on to the second line. The newline means "add what we evaluated to the implicit argument list"

Next, we evaluate `s` (get string in JSON object with a certain name) with `{` and `"answer_count"`. `{` takes an element from the implicit argument stack, returns it, and adds it back to the stack.

Then, we add the output of that to the implicit argument stack.

To evaluate `⁰s"score"/`, we are applying the dyad `/` (divide) to `⁰s"score"` and an element from the implicit argument stack.

To evaluate `⁰s"score"` we are getting the string `"score"` from the JSON object from the 0th element in the implict argument stack.

Now, the output of `/` is printed and the program terminates.

Comment: Save 4 bytes by ditching the API version (`2.2/`).

Comment: @Shaggy Didn't realise the API version wasn't required, thanks. Not crossing out 44 :P

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + [jsonlite](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html), 111 bytes

```r
function(n,x=jsonlite::fromJSON(sprintf('http://api.stackexchange.com/questions/%s?site=codegolf',n))$i)x$s/x$a
```

[R-fiddle link](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=3Q3JKWBE&version=1)

jsonlite is a nice JSON <-> R conversion library which works quite well. I wasn't about to golf a JSON parser for R...

Comment: You can save a byte by using the `http` protocol. Also, I'm guessing `142729` shouldn't be hardcoded in there?

Comment: @Shaggy good call, thank you. I copied and pasted too fast.

Answer (score 4):

## T-SQL, <s>64</s> 54 bytes

It is rare that SQL can beat (most) other languages! Instead of the API URL I went directly to the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/724902/answer-to-vote-ratio-by-question-id?i=142655):

```sql
SELECT 1.0*Score/AnswerCount FROM Posts WHERE Id=##i##
```

The `##i##` isn't standard SQL, that's Stack Exchange's format to prompt for input.

Note that the data explorer source is only updated nightly, so values aren't current.

Will throw a divide by zero error on questions with no answers.

**Edit**: Saved 10 bytes by multiplying by 1.0 instead of an explicit `CONVERT` to `FLOAT`.

Comment: can beat others, but not all :)

Comment: Oh maaan, I had another solution but I was in school so I never ended up posting it... Is my answer too similar to yours? Should I delete mine?

Comment: @icrieverytim Ha, yep looks like pretty much the same query, although I just edited mine to save 10 more bytes.

Comment: @BradC I edited my answer into a Mathematica answer lol.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 130 bytes

```powershell
($a=(ConvertFrom-Json(iwr("http://api.stackexchange.com/questions/"+$args+"?site=codegolf")).content).items).score/$a.answer_count
```

Performs an `I`nvoke-`W`eb`R`equest against the URL, gets the `.content` thereof, does a `ConvertFrom-Json` of that content, and gets the `.items` of that JSON object. Stores that into `$a` and pulls out the `.score` as the numerator. The denominator is the `.answer_count`. That value is left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

If the question is unanswered, this *should* toss a "Divide by zero" error.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>83</s> 82 bytes

Wanted to give this a try to see how it would work out, seeing as Japt can't natively accomplish it. Essentially all this is doing is `eval`ing a compressed version of [my JS solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143084/58974). As Japt *is* JS then we can require that this be run from the root level of `api.stackexchange.com` and also return a `Promise` object containing the result.

```
Ox`fet®("quÀËs/{U}?ÐÒ=¬¸golf").È(r=>r.js()).È(i=>(j=i.ems[0]).sÖ/j.s³r_Öt)
```

- [View it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=T3hgZmV0rigicXXAy41zL3tVfT/Q0j2suGdvbGYiKS7IAShyPT5yLmpzjSgpKS7IAShpPT4oaj1pLoplbXNbMF0pLnPWEC9qLoRzs3Jf1gR0KQ==&input=MTQzMDgz)
- [Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=T3hgZmV0rigiLy9hcGkuoWHlqGpEZ2UurG0vcXXAy41zL3tVfT/Q0j2suGdvbGYiKS7IAShyPT5yLmpzjSgpKS7IAShpPT7WDm+kLmxvZygoaj1pLoplbXNbMF0pLnPWEC9qLoRzs3Jf1gR0KSk=&input=MTQzMDgz) - the extra bytes in this version are accounted for by the inclusion of `//api.stackexchange.com/` in the URL and of `console.log` so you can actually see it working

Comment: o0 Why have you made the code a link? It even messes with the userscript's byte count display lol. https://i.imgur.com/SO2zgAy.png

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 124 bytes

```
N@("score"/.(u="items"/.Import["http://api.stackexchange.com/questions/"<>#<>"?site=codegolf","JSON"]))/("answer_count"/.u)&
```

Mathematica has a data type called `Rule` and it confuses the heck out of me. :P

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + requests, 149 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Mr. Xcoder.*

```python
from requests import*
u=get('http://api.stackexchange.com/questions/%s?site=codegolf'%input()).json()['items'][0]
print(u['score']/u['answer_count'])
```

Comment: The link is to Python 2. Btw, it throws an error both in Python 2 and Python 3 (on TIO).

Comment: No internet access on TIO whoops. I just used TIO for the answer formatting lol.

Comment: I think that (for now) `http` suffices.

Comment: [125 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcsxDsIgFADQvafo0gAOYKIuJo0HIQwEaYsWPvI/Rk@PxPnl5S9tkE6tLQXiWPyreiQcQ8xQ6DDUeQ9IfPXE2UaUr0rZHCSSdU//cZtNq5cOovq/AAnVhDcM5GcHd7/CvrAppFyJCyEfCIkLzTpHZEYfjXzbvc@OQy4hEa/6YlTVZyNa@wE)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 167 bytes

```
<?$f=json_decode(gzdecode(file_get_contents('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/'.$argv[1].'?site=codegolf')))->items[0];echo $f->score/$f->answer_count;
```

Turbo-fast crack at this. Save as a file and execute in the terminal like so:

```
php -f file.php 143083
```

Might be a way to reduce this.