# This Question Has _____ Views

Tags: code-golf, stack-exchange-api

Inspired by [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxV14h0kFs0) Youtube Video from Tom Scott.

Write a program or function that prints the current amount of views this question has.

That's it.

Your program may only access the stack exchange api, any other websites are disallowed.

### Output

An integer with the exact amount of views this question has at the moment. Outputs with the `k` for thousand are disallowed.

Comment: It's eventually going to pop the maximum value of the views buffer. By the time we reach that this challenge is going to be extremely trivial to solve.

Comment: is directly fetching the stack exchange website allowed? (https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203590/this-question-has-views)

Comment: @CommandMaster Sure.

Comment: @petStorm yeah but the challenge remains the same. Even if the amount of views stays the same you can't hardcode the value in

Comment: This question is half of [this closed question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/111115/31625) which was closed for being a dupe of a question asking only for the score of the question. The answers to those questions seem very similar to the ones here. For that reason I've closed this for now.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I am extremely worried that this is *the only* close vote, so you circumvented *all* discussion.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate This is a common misconception, but I have done no such thing. You, and everyone else, are perfectly free to discuss the merits of this challenge and decide to reopen the question. If anything, closing the question promotes discussion. However, this discussion largely doesn't belong here, so if you have something else to say on this matter I'd recommend making a post on meta about it.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman "I have done no such thing" - that is *exactly* what you did: you closed the question without allowing for any discussion. "this discussion largely doesn't belong here" - then where does it belong? I can only read your comment as "I do not care, go and complain on Meta if you want to".

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate I do not think the point of my comment got across. The meta-discussion about whether my actions prevent discussion does not belong here. Though my closing this question has done absolutely nothing to prevent discussion of the merits of this question.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>46</s> <s>42</s> 36 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

**Reading from the question-URL: 36 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)**

```
’ƒËŠˆ.Â‚‹º.ŒŒ/q/’žYì•3X&•«.w'Ž‡¡1èþ¨
```

-6 bytes thanks to *@CommandMaster*, by reading from this question's URL instead of the API

No direct TIO, since the `.w` builtin (to access a website) is disabled on TIO. But:

```
’ƒËŠˆ.Â‚‹º.ŒŒ/q/’žYì•3X&•«
```

[Try this part online to see the generation of the URL.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcPMY5MOdx9dcLpN73DTo4ZZjxp2Htqld3TS0Un6hfpA2aP7Ig@vedSwyDhCDUgeWv3/PwA)

```
'Ž‡¡1èþ¨
```

[Try this part online to see the extraction of the amount of views from the HTML content.](https://tio.run/##7X3bltzGkeA7vyJdGpvkTAON@6XJbg3VJE16SUsWKdoey6cPCsiqAokCSgCqL@TonPmDfdiHfZ6XPfMTuw8zZ3/EP@KNiExcC6gLSVGyV5TIAhKZkZGRkZERkZGZWRFMY/7Xv97@v//7L//27//57/p//cd//Z///I@//nUymdz/RZSF5c2Ks0W5TM5u3ccfFpd8WYTZip9OJvSCOU4ni7JcnRwfF@GCLwM1y@fHv3vwVTDnExYmQVFghmVycZHzYpWlRXzJJ2f3FzyIzm7dYvLP/TIuE34WZhFn8yyZMYW9XMQF@92aF2WcpexJULAL/MNexfyqgO/nmPfXmPdFGYRv2KPrcBGkc37/WMBqYCdx@oblPDmdFIssL8N1yeIwSydskfOZQL8A/MMoVYuiDMo4VFNeHr@AFhbHiBJidBwv58ez4BJLqvDP55enlu3pnu1HWqhNJ4P1BatVwpUyW4cL5T2r7INQV@kc6rbNqc11J3QjzRmuO15CF1wUefhDVcoGKcyDPFxMmOAMhBOHAfbgMbBNKr5GvAjzeIWp/3S9TCAzdtjpZKxHqwa0QKhYbrDZYZBmKdSZbDRbNlAtEDiXsNUwWx5/J7msODY00/a14xJ4T6lSlUVQKJfIde0al7wMWBosAW/8tgLGAn7P0pKn5enkKo7KxWnEgV24Qi9HbMHj@aKsEsXbEYvTuIyDRCkAZX6qq9oRW0Lacr1skjbqXeVAiry8OZ1k8xMkdbtqPi2gR7eXWedJq8gPSaJOtYjYBRKtVflor2@FRNwthBCmS3aHPPCb3zzFly9nUghtNPPwAfDPhhwCPHK0QHcsO3TsEXYor@Ky5PlJGORRq/ZivUTUdhSKsmUQp61i432yAxIxQQPnn4m6SGyk9S7Ucx6UWf6@xWk8T3pcKtKaDuuxwVZxv4tojUDp1dr50tTdSa5ReJoWqzjnEZveMGRv9sdsXa6nHHCIeMZmebZkL@HvizArS/XWrd/nAJERY87zYMmynM3WaUgNKBdBidyYlgU8cxau8xwqYcEyW8NPNmM0XEQ91TBiMIwA7ksoe7sAdOEZUMjrCpbBDcvS5IYFYcgLAZjYglV8wQJVVSftiVU0lME80AyAggM6fLWeBlGhztUoW08THoKkfkPjYb4qj8XHi3i5SmDiTiMOTZlfGJqhaZbmaob6Gjrl/rGAfjZYS75OeKF@tw7SMsRGkxyhRGWlhHr@2HpzPX/2zdvfhgiMBcVNCqUHoFZfhhoh4Bc8v6zkFLwOIzcCZqqCSpNzHK2goYjZBSFNeYAz3wGgrq6u1HmWzUFyBGmQ3IB8KQhU87abasHr4FpCCVaxLA9px0k8LY5fA6vkN8e6qhuqJd9UmC@6gLf3fl/8/aY4LoDNVY5QQMSFRmj4oRsEVuT3gQ5O@eUN9OmC87Ka9kt@XR6HRbFT81gEMNyOiYWhpUUhdQzDiuwo8MLhGf4D6usKejlZyIpDQ3ecMPQ1I9KqEVRX39frEhA7aYACdlPRAcm57Og1jznIlBlIh3qc394q7W7XCs8MShb13Cun3hZVxgQioHNCYw7mm0a@ffNiz6KYchKvFlnaltDd6ZnFX@4LLo42gXmubvi@a5h7wgCFZRNIwZW3ASRGH1132YM6QfTRaNMB9X6U6YD4EekiJNcqCW7GqfMgjfIsjg5o3yBUaXZ@ugZCXw0iAlX1Kgexcgla3IYg7tZDZKmoooLKFd3cqRWIO3fZu1ud7MPF1gVMzHcmRRqvVrwsJkesC4KN/OlCqYqraI68EC9f07TP8zt37w1C@X4k/dZeCK@yonwVJHFEQnMvtLtwugAI8S/TL5J1Duz1Yj1dxuWdf7hz@zPMpoDwXd6@e8SMI3Y7SIsrnt8eQB4bdGsH9hXzUH133l1mMKOcB0V58qd3k6@gqqfR5EQw29HkFXx8CdMDpX1/1Mvg7spg9DP8@QiMW5whMPkcxXtxUuZrflRmZZCcZ8slsCOln1hHxSK7SntpFfJPI4kjtbjfYJpfUdO/M/R1kHGTMl4CE62nyOZT/jKrprY7t0FhvA1UF/XdHmGZQQ6Zrza4uZcRcqhlDilfrssptDE6Rx22gF6XYxNrJkZRUEWA2tlGi9tc3Og6tzaY@bCHbh2VGtbSVq6VZVAuQK9TANVZPL/Hr0GfLXl0ij3aE0j45zlk/w2ohk9AUzunInfeTZ68fP5MOX/xYnICtFmBzsDByogeQ@NP2OQl/wPQL7gM4iQA/R5TixP2p8mLl0/hA33@8xEDpYZPoQvfFAgjWIPygvoSMRb7/og9@i49X6zTNyfsThuFL/LsCrRuNS6eZ9M44exzpmvshNnaXSg12MnQbgMajNXEKVaL8AAhQOnbb/8BUKWfPzNAKooLlLFNhn@A7/gPfMPcfxK5/yxyg3mE5tCjIgxWHJpBY4LF8xTU@nP0QAIxZOUXIvVfozSbjOEJhDnZIjih93ha4KyCxJzyOTBrnq1XqIL/@Wi0WJp9A@J0Bs2OiNBlCSMFOpzIjrwQZkmWA6bQgdA6TJkCZyPoFEpMPnv8@BH8kZ@K@C2HRF/7JTQDu2m03udBmGdUCeqUUObd91hkWKIPo78E4gZz/gLlAgBIUQkbzilUc6xsokpuuXgo@vKI1Slf5Ryn3c0Udsb@kVh50jQd3idxugD7sxRNHRYgjx5FcUn0k@MK36FnJre2TVmbFtM2q@k12ChJto5mCZgtPcNM1npsqK5qH1cjBewpMbxPgamUB89fXNCIna2TpG9ZbWgIu7WDPUQyzVK3rwpswXeBWmSgpMAsv6EqDQnm3VL@a75alzT9/jYr45k0gAoh9FsQd0N6ma2@CPLtUKrOO4huYpqeJBn6UicnEw6qxoTcBflLwGFyotueq9mWZnlHE2C4kv8W/VInk9/VuuMLmEmxEMJ9sC4X3@QJfK/9B5gMYpOcBpAN7MyrLH/zHFTIJzDxpAIaapQDHjyAil66k3cTmW/UGXrU8VkBer96QCaldA0tgdXZav32LUhimPcWMIWCUlKwII1YvajCc5hQJ3GBZAaB@TKYPkpxZoAxRiITiIOvv@VXL4P5OboAoa7fB3mK4@hkFiQF5IlToF75YhWE/MEMNGMkF0ACTWOVcIFclZMUGdCDwkWcRF2q1Ur7KGFSPof6LznqOi/QQfM4ybJ8cpLC2KkwfZGFcZA851EcPE3JmfBVtlqvquYAbcoMxGpV7@T7o8kasEd6z97wG0j3w9C19GhmGq7hOeGUe5YVeDM98CN3GllmNHV9z56Ftul7esS1qWNEs8AIzCBwZ2aoA6IltnNiTrk@01xD8SLdUNwp15SpZXiKZ3PftXxf930fMuccsHM13/SxI76GyaMAGjY9gOihwjc5McULan62YehAxiAkkx5TdM92Dcs@mkDfXwZlAE2a3I/iS7ng9m2drlzlYLnwXDGNb0HixMs5SbVv646IBfFV@LLOSaY957MXX6mvV/PPi1PT@FWwXN2bn@rfThiMWigID2Jx49sJwqxWNeRbVf8Uqi6WWOUxoHU2oc6YgZ4wwgabths2vjimph@/gdkhVcJ8Hb8uChrBoAi/4PwhB5bjEWrNhaDg90hiIV5oVPErGMUVcYMQGap6K4P5vCE8IJBwmKpAXKc8LJ@C@phfBsnT9Em2hmFzogFkfglDq0C4qFKKbno3qZRq6BXIg19o6skAwVCkv5sI5/eJfjSZZhHwnUHVAyjz@@@x7iy/wWwwiuU44l9Avmc8nZcL4Bfo6CR@wyMYlsXz4LpKN3Fwgao08g0gv86mX5FWyFMY8FRFcP3b9fIhNCVBN/nXWYLpgI/48DSN1gVoJphoIWqX86dAkq8ChDnqV3u6nB9DTlopQREjSz0JCixl67PItqe6YXs6DEH2jhj7K8EPgJMclc9JyyBRg0mCPvhUm7aAvnBFPxSLJCdCJte2K6AyabJ3ZBuCSSAvwijiiAN/Poigu5dxUZxn2ZsYhS/lUORnJYhQXlTyOUiS7IqWlb5ZJVkQFV2Z@RSHzxMSMp30b6BhTzKYbNC9XH8DwR1yyk0Qi4YJpeVVI71CXU@QYZmlqOEIAk3CJAZmhCkM3osH0yJLYOrCGQ2mMOp9ErztTA85mkhhk0nXiEfQQMR5ruEORLp4mj7Ms1UERiQIIMoX5G/EK1ADpVZcvIFhkge/z/Lo0XK1CIq4GYWgI1H/CcJ9zdFMQ31MWqSPxWc5LrtZWt8AUCgKSCJIGUiQ5ZLKVyBxYMaNvubfrWOyfvJzFCMAiebQp1GVQ8L8flQzIcNTLXh5HoQL/gVaRUAJUB9eF8dBlIG1ST5yYBXDCPxpZPtTnaNYx@/Fm/qrPjWnvuXovhaF4iuZCQpMVKVCUqTO6nArmPIwnE5dLrIKKdPUNNXNwLOnvjudygzXwIE5V75LYPKo80Wa5cy4HWmOp4l8qGUquBpe55mavm9wj3uBZTZ5GhC2rfOQ217gGuLzgier@rPrcMPznJmhG/KzMOMUGKrUNCReTQInMHTfCTVrpovMMOFOMxgFShWE0abmVAunVhjMppHIvCSjskHcmDpeFM4cV59VGUAO4BplQ8kwsk2uma47k3nI8L9sXEQ1tEAP3cgJjagiKZjOJaieN0qHHlNzZgSWhdqhI/LVrkNO1kadU3wVRkydqGmG4818y9A8v8lAlmOdx5@F09DyAlszXJEHiNkDbkPLp9wEk8gKe3nSVnWm6QYzI7KcwPTqbMUaJjmhx9YZA382syyfz8KKO6@WUYN1pBle4DlWoAeS1NJR0e9izwK9yYW/9kxWKEWv8hqUD6GsKjjDL@M8b7XHnXmOaU6nmm@AiN0@GPteoE3f4KZHiFR@HOm7bYc0k6ZeHJ1OqhcFV5LO7pMwPsP5@kgts5UCc8I7kIE4juH1RFd9vvwe4FG2@8dV6coqweT@8tRZbfDSnHDxGDR3zt5NQTaBipYHUbwG41k1bL68x5QrPn0D8mLk6zJ7O/bpDcZbjXycZtcwAEGYXZ0wbXVNf3Ub/vnMMx@0K92eTdS@PU@FxtZcAssTpkMKTGJxxD574Dxkv2DxEkNqgrS8V3mDTqTbSJmCNffmHoPhTXrWCQvk/Pf9rZrAz3m6vvhiXZZgLPeo/gC48Yq92yx@D1fpC3QirLIYFcDRqiusjRbWD@rW1DS3Vtej/Si@DfSi@DDYh/RplqWlMguWcQJo3T4H9TTmOQOj7faRfJF5hI/IxzLSt/TZYw3/O4RMxSpI2buaDFX7a/eMUoFutb/VmxskMREdIqUwHIApoCeDKILBTg1sIdfC42SBz@ydrO1qAWrZL1osMtAh5@fnTY6tUEUbB9rUA1EP9uHB/VlVwwNQtMo2g83iaw6kSPisRA/pL@8JE@qE3K330DFaKjBNzSFryAXjVQ0CejGABjpJi0w6XzKDRvMmzg/pT93lU9RpG8aO@CxYJ2WPi6SDD8dqh3d0A3EVCcL5l2b5MkgkyjHo4qnoQXoHBS4tcKkF86W8189VUbBuoIUKED2kxlTpqKGNpKIR20rCzqechBB@BCRBKS@ret8SatfADpq@wYEofEZHpfw4MCzll8FxKb71JZ2O/xgaiToN/xsXr0NZh0TsUL5hMTuQE8wtXMkkl1EcnTz8AxkfL6tOU5/H6CnOZqUageYvgN35cjb7w6lxxOD3j/h7jmx1enueBze3j9hXxOKX/PQ2zre3735/qzsIGjmTgYmHdjp7B8nIF6KveqJoWCpvcjmxQJ/HO2OqHiuG6JqNWeac/txjYkonJh4cJDg60nV3kOJA/lsbAz/zZpfVnpYgRN@12aQvUnEhCepfBWhl9kpv0SFy0dUqqVsSPmmMlQpWSWqH/nQErupCjn5V5LViQ9W3R8MQgurXL5@xd2LaEfhI5HCM9AqcL3j4ZrhFEoC7gRqVEZVUrXaxFlFgoJKvQWBmO2vSNypqynVq07dW9gwM62Szi1HJYLpqmli4PbfFJQzvsF/zOmk0dOrFLTKEIAsdtwfmYVyQN6rus18Dk74EgTHc2QPKyBNocoLNrhmoThmAU9V3MsvCdXHENgkjvgyqPY88/K8F8RxX069LLFsVG5PiraxsY7yNFO7OGedJVgAF5IhpMS2@9OeLLju2SiooZCrmoJc@74rMn8AK0L1tCoc3qnB4WxQO7z0sAcPaaQoIorynzq/ao1r/D0aCUUvCw2HInOFu/4jWRB/mvrbEGICRIbLD9NhYSFef/@YPMwoxqVspF9EPMGgQyMWDoogLFEoXWMfzZ0NDpk07Gn1aNfJQq0piSMl5WN4B2XjEOv/cbVs11GXw31BXdBKrDocS7WSpAPZSkaqgGYHusYgjUNZ@MeRZIB5vf6l4VWwBCdFFva51q@ojLlsoBU@gbfUnwaxDX5DBB9OLoeSNJOSZgf4YTLz4AtvD3lUU0bRfvo8h@y9ZttxXJZcCpU1voYn35UitmJqomNa9r0r3VF9Rl8p9S00nkXbV06hHjdS/IZW9o4HHbwmgDGQTpnmjdw993f5B6t8oo@3aBfeA/gzr/iM5@6r/SLZNzX8446c1SpGhvwT@BH7cpoBqjRhrcas2qgi0hllLONFbLb9arK512HnUus2QqcobwfOSTEGyWgR35JdTrd826VBuWpbzhKIoRlFvzZ2yFVoP5iNcj4IOWR1OMWOn6vSDkeXQCbOaJT/zPK9FALEozUedeboQWmWZLUkDGnHKPXLwv0E/hG/jf62mo1rTsVlI0ampqiNVu46Plo7nbTgXB8ROu30vnj662OCapnc3ZvOKSXo46a0uxU/Drelq4Y9wVagh/Pk5LlrvMMkODCZsa2K1BtRmjm3buQb2STXLg59fnnaWS/fdIzYAdGwVFarorKK2qxjV11aKrP5d263gCcsJP5Mxxd7V@k0laZUMvmCX5cLIJEG/5Wux5WM2/m3kQ4XdNEsiiXo1w2NS9VnwQ9W2Po/I1svPlWFUscULosvRbYx/KNBKYl9nyyC9fUQJRxgV/Wue8jxIjkD1imcVxFkevBkBCQPnTbnOD4dZzMaQBOq8wJyHwwQddQToOepAMO4XcXg42GWWZiNwMQLqCvfAvgcFEhAQPFt12FS3tV/2vstuT4FjYdoucV9/pdEplT@AsCRLZ2Sy6ehzumps6oFdS3rftozodNJQBbmWBCuw61j1VCEr0dw0sYcWgipJims@Wqe5PTO93eZmOF33a@nYahv1tQqeBBjeifKZVMkTNmGTWoiQV2wccGudnKl6003hIsjHyzUsx97VEwiUt1v9DKMx7H4VTtU@d5CvtSY4T9GQ6ZOqRBfZkAGpNXwoitJUUhenckqeXW2iXqzzaJNVgQ6dDF1wI1SQwQjYhZi/X/@QPdwaP73SQw0IeZK0oWzDugPtJAmKUqGoXgG4X1IoRFtQ2YsAGFKWlthxGDUzjRPS@oQRX@dZYzwgmpxHrJ2ys7MrAMIRNDiI9hspBGC/9tS4Yv4evntz2JK@bdJcLi70R0avWLeasXHQh70Emie8AZXvi2q0k@mGRF7HJ0AuIbXTEqRWXcPJLM5rbqyc/YrUV1tlOvla5ZsyQtetiyToJefR3o1t8h@MXV30YCS50KGH3DHwx/Maf2@lXg8uhYpPHU@cWXuYe16VdmxJW94ECdcG9MoTRp/@cEfV7va1yv63YvRTNvZlMLmDlL4VKX0LUvo4UvooUvowUnoXKWMrUsYWpIxxpIxRpIxhpIwuUuZWpMwtSJnjSJmjSJnDSJldpKytSFlbkLLGkbJGkbKGkbK6SNlbkbK3IGWPI2WPImUPI2V3kXK2IuVsQcoZR8oZRcoZRsrpIuVuRcrdgpQ7jpQ7ipQ7jJTbRcrbipS3BSlvHClvFClvGCmvi5S/FSl/C1L@OFL@KFL@MFJ@O07iK9ytyNQ0k66avl7QnwyGXO5dV9XmFLMxH@3vu3tY2VE77SYKxdjmFB1W@FoW4jK4VqR5IJz1mNCsEVAKWDyVe0y8bTpXK9NCtICpP40JvMIGmJHsfTJoe0Z/nd4vUAAPKWQP90o0H1oOx5dZlpTxaqjFT9NZ9kWdWjcckzHCYcviUHuZgaI85FLD1vWN4Yz95Y3hXJurG4P5PsHiRqvTMVTU6vhlLVph28dp33EZV2zbW7/rRnpsmBFbmK2/WDe4wNZ2BGlN3CkkKEH0el3U42xwEW9zmW9zWe@HX8GL4lxs@gNMyvzDpcauZZKmO6pAH9yvwGQQwWhXCYuvKVxL1MfrJPk9IjMsU3fYco2M00DiDkU7sHg5bzz1QIFp3noNqkCrbetCH0rS/hymjbAjtT/iYZYHokMF@0MDamoVMATLFs5tWjTYb/rFeokbGA1SbtDb1x7dYlFhn6W1DyLB6DpzC1fsV/ZuYLiM8cRGw9r0aY2wwfL/CMyKYz1uI9lRpbpfai2ql1wMpWYbiW39SBw8gnvvB3xU7c6Ri4YNV7Y4sh@gslkBb/tRxuhwUfKi7C6NbBXCHyZvP1C69tvcienptUldvr5W8GHAcT7g1RssKbhqK5tJn7UMNlS24iECxLd5wMOEBzl5QhctMPz6ouuSH/M3Dk3amzTribZNSdgWAC250JIFTcxU0wWOxttt58u/EaTRRdjv8boVqBlsaUd7bEqBgyW2QSROOQxktda5wdFbgR42227Mf/0Jcxd9Owp@tWkqLr9AnKrQ2FIo5K3F9YOiM0YrAFlelRLI1vD0LaH5G9bF@4H5Z2m@bNg@dbREEAMDF3l4wtZ5cuf2e50NhJCL4@rkruOX/A/HV9lsdtyuRPmaz9cAScUvn786pZK37@KJLwDszm1MxvPsPioWWTmCBHwYwAEPY0fTHAOs9qIcLe5/GvJ9ATX9uLQjDD4W4USIw6ch3VOq68clnsTho5CvXHw68kFdPzr5Ghw@AvlakSM/OPladf3o4m8Il49AzhegXOs/OCGplh@dhF0sPhLxjE9CPOMnQTzjYxPP/CTEM38SxDM/NvGsT0I86ydBPOsA4jWa/I@2StQcy7@CfzM8Cb17DUAQ4YGPccjlvQpqmmBaHB3j/r65OEbodfG5uHvldMuNKywoTicinmlyNnCqb3PwTS/s9@Oh0IoCPrzhxBg/csvfH4cdN2cceKtJ9y6Tg68fGQjkHjxv6vPL0855Ux8Cf/OUKoTePqXqA6DXh0ABzM4hUB8Ac/DoKIDfOTpqjKNnvMSbxLosXa5CyUiAQyTPiiWeKoIZn@FOhmNd0RTTPcY1umN0UANb8VzFV6xL3DxHhzTRYom8o64@2muF@z3WaTyLeaSUC77E6@rwbE0SN3jb16ajd9PLNb6Zou20Ig/W8LkVWlvsbe6p2LW3rc7zA@xuk/TAM7Ma9w02Gz5M8/8//tKxpvLfPjHkpqFJxTEd1/296kxUwYJV2TSjkV2z63CucF2U2VJBFu5loVPn74sPFUvLU8vY60KpHuXvxYU8pphd0MrEpFWPLHy1vNYNtrxWkC/ZPI8jFsSKWAlkC13TJizPsHV4PAqAbF920QKjoFCn4gp5MAdOtr8fyDH@WX1hJHJ0fRBnmc1huLOV1kLgdVg/FcpA7jZyeO0XyPc8DvDGjxWeEAy0wVP2RSLSHHL3qpUf@fUqgDEFtKdTjXHuw4U4ieeqUKpgEhJj8Al@goE2tkgCfYCIRnGQZHMavGlwWb3K5rRS8Kj6s8FDz9tA26gjkHW6itMUJFi3TTAzQYODVJnyfnPpU1wAc@VcuVrwFOb75QaPNSenDydv9qUCjcgQpfmKVtjCN/gi@U98bL9IROrMp@KQ14tKE7igDlTxeov362RJ/nadktRjXT5M/OJyLusj2VfVJltdHYfLUuIOtixTnW4dfQb1vXj0QF4gBZ9eLKsTlSe65tYHKk90e0J3xH2RXZ9OMAgavjJIPLuPh8IylDeWp1o603XVNxMF/nUUUzXgQbOYrurOpQFPC3i3jFeGqnsLfLp0VE1/BiV1i9mQ4hqJYqiWxUDLx78Ws1TDwFKu/XapuKoGBbwQ3m2fwbwK5RRREzyYqu0U8MXGJ4tVaVao@i5irDq2aiBYE7BzEyjoAq6hAvXBX09RXV9RHQeAmxY@FIrOoHZ8Vx0D8kE5E7JZhuq5@IMgPQwI96CBeIqLQRQAA8VULdV1oBQThQEzzAfwdQ@TbISfEAII2HFUl6pVfU8R@HnQXBuxgWbYSADHhoyeCa3WVcNRTZd@mV5AVb5P9fh@qNomVWQqgu7wixRUVISqwFf8gT4xL@HFebuEJyCU5sKrg6SwgX7YbBdzeS7@wg9VajkK9aeHVDID6EOGf4kZFKQ6ZPFDzKk7qmcoBny24Ae61XOwOvgmCGdhW7EPxYPqigp0G6hDyUBW7B5A23NCJAJmIbJhnTZgwZDNoGZD9VUP/8Vu9S6hJPGY6RP5gEeQV0yD4CNRfFM84D@vHGRDqOMVVLyAHxN5UgdG1eHBdC6BTu4Tw1fNSxP4L8TIf9WwsbddD/5dqLYHeQwEgdwJnWJK7rSALaAjgSjIS8ANPvaWlwChfC8ENof/cYcuoGFRi/AX6qQWaRaSUzxAHoCEdFR1pBSwn4mwNIBkAHQDErESbJGGvKkn1AGQ3Q2gXoZ/RRdBNyCPI7UsXfwj@86lbnWo75DOABhY3IGypnioMDOAyIJfcEhjFzmAOLCCj50N/9CJGVBGB5yAYoQK0d4D/sUfbDRmg75UgadhpMAQQKICaBieJmYAEWLZCfwC67swePGJobSAQvDrWUg/YBLLJXg6/hg0wD1BesQZR75NT28nuPYHWvxlkN9RFFoavItTCUqulvzSNQuxBRnjh8jpRHRkPewFA38LaDBwA1JL9@AdshGxkHNRhgDfu/YC@jYwWEUL6gsSXogzsq2DjOSjRABaICFtm56wazQmOs9ABnd0khLYsQzFaK8/DeorXUcqoxhCcQtD03XEA4od6guknYGJ2KE6/epCIpoktSwSldjZ7iWIwIUClLVp@FgojGz33Ie@Yg5S1rcZdhn@eqpJDbEIiIdt0O3qSbNFU4DhfF080BeNRiCyso4iovpgQHXQjwDTMIhpBM9YSAhEAcEYyBEKNRhEmgkDUNDTEj@aQzVaOEgs8YAi6xK5G0W8C4ONBBvyOPyrOr4QpT4NIiQhpGGPu4qQOCShXHoANhKZLagH2duUqaqF4xHHEIl6LArdIhoPmSkNZQeKV5fmN5jxvFCjvDp2s4EEAfrTADKJ7C5W4bivAE0ckzi/IS@gAMH2u@KJphTBiZIjsU4UgYZLE6b3CiYGqtS8hLEVyHnVkvyDKKA8MEEcCXyB@sgrMChxwvKIJU3REPg1ALJtPPE11aCZGDvG92hCxxnMQmQYinWm0pxo@SgOPaxHM1Bm2jRTynlJN1Ay4rCC4QvcCV1FP54PpDI9nJgQWd9DymH/AaldZB7sH8Dcon4SvWLJeckQHUhTtCKYxqVfqS3QPaWuC3hrtpyb4GmBXQ@0pukJvmJ55DKaN8STGF7QMJ2UA8jrkZRFDgFuRB5BpjepRhTnLj3oOC/jKMP2W/SLH@tJyjVp0sB57BIGnUl9jZqHQlIFx5N4qrvalijZ1CsAyNQJkPsKZz/sahemKgMlsolNNO2mr6mrdaGIGELQap54QoyxdyXfCKwqRcsyhKLlSdECD7VoobHu1rKFvkCfETu5KHkM0mlspBaOBVKiHOoehzgYG2PRg6gHCIkJOL8JfcPFqQ3GOPYpicpCTAbAk/QOkykqQ9DBkB8ainxkIT@TMqc7JJWwgkRgoHshjVGajUxspiJwdGjo2ag3Uefi8BZMgFqO/sT2E2AZVC2pBD5YDsh63XjmIC8xF2vAQaEZmGw@c1BUA9uaWBDp4yxIdEBFuk5CAnpNcxagJr6CgYJy17EvcYZdgCqH2ocLbEKPWMGCPotEKFLPap8Zj33nkTcwoQHrCXUM9E7gPNDEvHpiAsHDjCdaA8V7/NB77A5Ni0A27YlGMktHPQv/W9iXZgJyq5noEH4DTbdt0@9Dk98s54Hx0J9IFK2FblwSJoOZjYfOwy/sKrO7mRmv@hgyCA8yewfMr75Z2DaAyfuxzXITlmDHjqNdlQmPpjfbiiryYnIqIu5Ymu4sQ7e47DbKZW4ZJDtSgAotrKoMBsnsaq7E@ax3r@pvRc77xwtrS1WrXcC3NK5z6H5TceVMwutfYrx2KpsxHYbb7@j2oAcM7/BYp3EZ84LFaZis0cXZ@Ao6V2lVrlTh8RcVfSnTkMeO6NZzOh6iKI/YEs8UBsu7KHmEd6NjhF5V3Q3dkBVVd90UrMwYhmWmR6zAy6IQUpyzN2l2BWwy50d0XdZ0jZtvxacQckFBdZyax6stpA5qb4AyLVNG/15c4DjjG2s1A0suezlCaIFjcvYqLuKy1y@DQ7JGbipOfZcYomtCCen4RxiG9KDIHB3k12mB9243A@x0QqcXomNsP4cI/nOO3dC4PbyW18Prez1g2vTaTg@YimEm0p/pOAUxk/mgH8MDpsGbKR4oCb@KXJQGBUFv1OiRUnFSt6tnSqc0zNwXd/ePBTFGxvxWH1nrMtA6pZMNvfM0KMXt85Uwq94C2lFyOjmuEpa8XGSQfY49IcnbeFjZLFHmeXalM5EfHYIr9OW@xt1YVcqE1htCedvU6SSbzfYQaB1/5zhrxelqXcoLlL9rX9I@YaskCPkCZBzPTycvCB0Ytqy@9@4v//a/gAGCZM1xfWkTRwxnTeiOq9OJYWkNeymiUvl7cSGa2jRamcUcxnWXdV9UJN5wESoVsYXHVHxKEOlCgYGHUkp@q7qH9twoZ/Xnz4SLkvLUiQq1f0nXRotTMhQY1fnWuWHPcSVbvvlS0wJfqha/39CDBEcF3ZJURlv4ckw7cBnZM0JjRseY7l9C@jPMDCAS8nCp9lvUbNwHNrOFhgyKjBuIN3qHn51qxhBX1tTFNQJct9DwJ7VYsTyBXwUvhIGprVoHkfxQlWn6Rgnw0OyLizKpJ2ClOyTR0zywVoJMRu52wMCw@oslzVpFpNDdqcMrJQ2M@gl6bslmoZLlKM4VS9P6N5W3yl8qtDKZcKXIJ2fPsgAnWRhOPeHUXlaS0khwWWtZow2KRlAI02Cq5LS6BOScZfVqxxAtghCyFusEFQE5cys3Yh1psbw2azJ06u@RU/TRIsa7vgZ0s5fxqqDZXWTES9EqcCPCeERO3z9G6Xs2dIXz/SypMKqbIZfDlon4BTxhTEVBftPvdLybC6nAS1osE8e5gnY15xEQsOKnFeZIxRWqbbZI4nr1BBc2GkkOqkAMMHDtb2ilBZfP22K@zi7rE5PYFhm4Y@2kGg2kf@LMD7oHalUo6iSShykCf2PiCDWq@8dJ3OOhXndtW@Pceq9lBWV5o8jrMjvrZpsaocx1UayXS2BCoQzeuQsItMfTxmWghlV34X9DFNh5jUJzR@ieV4RaXnVFqLghdFJ3JtZSdSY@VwYOXQ3KFIETNlBit6xFwvhUOCKkJme9dlTSaa/5A8bpCvEQq@f4VpPnJlvnLK@vOT5hrnbkm/5kgL/PxKct4mdHE44k8FZ9bSG7V0umQYT3SUL/Uz2yFS5e/wuWjfg4hHsHLcqnT87@8j//e7WmvfGZrmGENteL3pv5uq3r4NDJLpH0bVbECc7IB@Fp7IWnb@@NaB@PIVwN12XTPEvf8sOQNfdCFqDvje0GJrLIVo4ZM1eC/tzYlnQbk1Kc4k5gMaUMyb1h@37gkl95m/HnZTA9JaCbM1q7ru709VQUkB3zNcf5V6BWXWtVHBIn0F/8FyJ3naLuo1D/wGQ0JOAPmPQkypWY1LbMeYbWm/Ms1QGjFlQK1XZarkVdrmbaz7CEprr@K91uvqMz8onRflcMdIAbemLgmoSnWlZIfm@Pli1Nh5aV8Ml@u/RUA5KNBP2ZBvmWcU1DcVXTCHDelMtuPi6xe09snII7yZD6DFfhmK6L8ujOdHZ7FNtcH4tgvywXIk6EuDSdwi7q/Y@1eqkNSc8Ok@9g8AAUS35J1lrxsfm8kfGbzD5Qb48PRYGLRXUDDCiVK3kwSHd0PGiB6g@SdjUnrUnnSEoS4Q5b5fElqBjwztB1ho6rjz2aRGqCFyqsxoNuDhlh3Wa/r5vJeKU/MS/1J9qlRb54HBQW@ZggNRSrIQwXKxxQGs1L44ldUJgExUzAEMXVJUvBwQZ/F4p5qRghLnIzixacQNVUzFd@qOOSt8Fo9RT@NV9h3rfPTeZidAhqsRhwAMPylbXQL00cjxTB8MxnHnOgcl@1ElqcfgYgF6Z8Bv0VV8a9RC5Ie6jhqi6oyDpovg6jRXFcqMERzwRw4yMPyoop6zH5Tx88KMXh3vsMR3kf7@b46gSideB1B8/Xsnw9bOhY8e/WfA2DQWF4OTJeU4pHepJTmu4K/@DR0VLvBW5tR@@ddzC3XUQoWPITRsXY93c/cLSIhv0O2/W@gwUYCOYEN7EVXAF/1VqlwqmmNfVoOBVd6kZ7GQtnA5VmFdfHJc569hAmnAVzFLK03krHoaI9q6p9@9zAhSoNhqDxyn271BS5xmW8guGCEyIMvQWOUOPt0HobgHEBAVdxhY0INiMkWSqGXMDwAODkJU5g5G4dIIfwMXLPPlw8YN63itbM@QSZ8Vz4HlBsZ8CQaLkUYMCEh6lAG6GSVF@1tCZ4NDid/OlX362z8h7kYWlwGc9p7hBpR@KHBgjWyIh35bd0nSTNP38@zF@AzXxPHoVODTzmCbbCf50H4hX/g49vlxQ6gevFIHc1gwLxbBFkQ4EojOIPKFJFM0RYiIgyE98xkcKknDo0xBCReS6G/GEOmwJzKN4LBDwuSbsMV8dNEf5oizVyqNrHSC@MHMQpwHBEaBRF2kAePwA@rLQrzZdxchqIcs0UcWge/DxxVQ9hUzQYxRLo8seGfBQAqRsUEINzFL5iSKZPEWt@Fc1jGAKgQeEvhk0BF6YfYOAko38E@QRBXB2xxfgcpJyOESYU@EgP2HiMRsSYE2ojxVxRrAFGdpkyTlMH/REbhKqnh4v@UDX1AUoHBwMRRUgaEt9mIsLQph6F@n2EYWArXGgRjF@MjKB4HR/TdQqDw1ARgwKmMMaForGG3Dxj43h0Rbs1SupBOrKC3RlQG57loaqWWRQkWxaS76@TLT6HvsNq3DtVgriYtPywW3xP2Ij@1ASS5QJXe050nJUOkRVYMSvW093iYmtL8M9LALUzU1ePAbwV6UPbowK5Ap6XDGPlyQ0dgFqAvlB0FJOWkM1qlWA3Lvt4ebau5R6P9fDWrm@6fUFi9cO73Tq022mKEC7z9@rv1rR364fq7oe8DGK8uzNIiysZRhCkN6zaMVawm2zNlnSvyiK45Lc@pK9H@3m8jw8a6qNGa73vcgnNHdoA@uHcYRzKHYjKRxIK1Z/nAHLvzB8qJGoOiotwXRQkETBQJk7nhTCuM2gURsWQuIiL/eTFIXJjL/mxP4/txV@7A3uOcVEfxtBxgDe@fgzecg7lLaqZrYuPyF90fS37prj1qXjrGXpk2DKDSUg0pxsuRfwmKX3rYzLUTmb6JIw0XRdxyouCGOpzzCfUq4uPNZu5h/JUhdFH5KkvJMgfj6cWcY7Req0wOtB3cKs7pgZRAdYYWFjr4qfAYfeP@3rwePTD8EI7HVkKLQoXGOnwPs7egeX4DlAZVbedL7HIRVVEbnbsLNrDd1Z9r50ADyjsACeTIEkoArMXqIlgP8JyyH6jgSjDKtIcOBYOCiLAiqo2vr@7V39i9txUxkJ3@r4ssNuZbvZisz0Rm73Qu9HZl4rxBJ2qSzCiXXiyEJ5zqAtJBsg0rCrimBrTE@zCPA@SHUElIqhluw2L/PGiYtS28TpopLbhVFvSu41ZmFtCITY0z4ETP8J1jmczNiG9A4uU7Ur643vMhGbTubLKrnC5X7M3oqrWdeCPrJ@G8GTUxGoHYU72X62fJfrkw@gzhKYQO81Tx@FNUUrzwoO/19WW7wjXILVdMmhzejS7nudOy0Ai4OiUv0rVBIEWfWodCVCHE1VBoBu7zjsTWyfUtU/BGsatoSmHuOdWPwyuhThFt@KueaBcsUv0j3fMIQb1LjLrZFSfIcRN5t9AaRGUm@jQiiPWQ6E6C5i7T/dgqg9DmxTyM8RnD6zHCSlWTnF7wt52wi7MPMIMRRvArJFrByMe5F/psw5Wzw6UBM/wHokVhgaK0VIfAjI8AjrZe6GYW5rxwbb/wVLFGO4dVfQO9EqJ@zjKC0w8gexHPfFytKsvrcNlkHAq7CWHyFvwMYRR1@0wLJF2M11Xu@339MBsTD5nDGFTWjtwlP2n6veJbjgmYROEtAIMIpQi6FrVj0zgW08SwWbgEVKKPNNEqLFnmDS87axXNgxS6KFu6bHDeUTenhq2n1IxQu9CXAkyGWpko2ksb6pm3fq4NvMekv5jaQtj41o7eFzrf3u6xSC8nOPtXmhMt49AqiJF9xEDu90pH8kn977coB/CC/oPyQmdJm1nh66j7AN4ogvogxnjyDf0H5cvVuu3bxM8q@@jiQvb9g9hEcj@QzJJ1b7t/PGVzPUBnFGB@FCeMI@cOnr5R@IJPMbx4/GDcxA7OD8oN4iL1LdxAh7qx5d4qGXxAczQgvKh/KD/2NyAE66ITPt4PKH7zkHTiO/80CqFaOEeSoWMEvxAtUJA@WDecM0P5Y1NF/rgRuBGlabDXbO8ZbWOqda7NgyLfcLC3zuR24dnb/hNvSHYD0PX0qOZabiG54RT7llW4M30wI/caWSZ0dT1PXsW2qbv6RHXpo4RzQIjMIPAnZmhPtlvPynx6Eo3DjDgux3M9tsn3Ws@joN6tUDsfyxxy3R7@/Tobuclu8JthrTXkCCI@2/E99aO6s7@6wdRxIL@GkHtat0H88Z@AcxndJsnWTGs/bxYXuss0ViuIWGq83D7e0NxBG2LYtqyc2XLuQbLxOseYFAsK4riIl0sjTbgZ0F4yDPBew7xyqWIWJieJmdAq@2HAOyBX4tc7QFEizYF7l6YJtUSizzpFT@dTh5vOYdy@5gdY23clMzTnS6qYIC/e9QUMdQF7xnntQF@9jV@3L2et9ltY3Wu8hjXNLd3aBFc8g5G4z37ArJ@UNcOrzEetkyyh5tFugdoaba/trbTv3KALTilsMRqagRkZQgBXnI3fz/HyPaTgcJFnERN3kFydvZndzaO0yx2/zhLup59cdA3z@v97eKI8Vsdw60SeipuWri5M1un5Kphd@6yd70cYqFMxbME7ty9B7rEvVvdDFBBliRfifO7VeB5@fgyW92xtSOma1BMTO0Slc7JIN2jm0kuDDNL@8iAJpcy6DUeOImmXYTUs0iZJfy6tXV9JlyEeJSOzmZXijiRaP81uy3T/HJeDwSxgV6c1rDjIHlc7C7qKo8BCi0IqMXl/PPLU25Og6k9NSLfDuQW5JazZ3iX4/YQgS7jtBl1hMS3btUndO88U3kZsWQ@GTu2eeDQ5gFlYuzgZ0UpgGZvWseIU/iBSJPHSrdVYHiVK7vNEn6f3ZpDEPBM6v66WGv9Y3QbTt3YFQj1jjFQQxSsuGkBwKC7gEyVNh8XF3Kl84TCEY5YkokbAE6MIxZhOGYqXj3S9Z9kS77n/oydJtEOQmwxsWqT6CZbBzlHXtikFZ0BD3DroNJqxB23Un4AOmJUxTgZdSLj7@pA1x2BCntxRdXSMpg3jRQvn55PDGrgS6j98H08402jBZFJ58SHH6NxJjXuG6z@o7YuFYHQzRlmx@2kT99OW7SzxuHAIS@@ZMnQXLG5BJd1luAA3@66661bA6d@1dc3VOtE1WScxqsVaM7S5O3NS3JSKTluMVzBzAES/VFaomVGqWD@r8imwxdpO8MMivpciM4mNcvnx9XYrWYOmvIbmKBJY8hUb3LfPf8Gq1XClTJbg5GK3hF1leJcbJtTm@tO6EZ4F83mBEqnGtUxOHRH8iy@bjf81qayg5Srb2epVjbb9kyxPJmh/pisl@nWQxb1VsvRvTB4elpH@wFbHgzUKaiHbxS8C4Utp17r7J1GOB8bmmn72jFGcSsNtkGhoF@nGf7NJ@iwnAbC2UuM/K46ij0JCnaBf9grLCmOnFnoQ6uHbX07AaMuQD1ACcugbTuBuQRDSGzARVItwRLHnykUgF@6YUaZxTnaoMsTQHjcLrzVndibxgfFm7qFV4UiLnsftNpakB8Ub@pWb3FXDR7atJnUN3JBcSUkVlMPOk132HTKpqFCN4wpxh5n3bVI2DRpmQMk5IH6JBDN0BQ8Nd5hunFi6ieG8y@TPY9/mYUK7d4HqIAQkINHO7eHlDGoNA0Xgwzl58CdJUpefMHvbaxeVlhNzkowyW7uH2OOg44xPJw4Z/vvxenRIEQtd6/9UBUXfg5wSjyD75IEY@0gE1Fw9HNxEaegdaFrYKDXnBPdO9H1f6kJFLyfE2AndVpcgyMb5ild9xl2R/F@HCOg7KJWXcn@R6INjy6UwzgHkWUjA0KDuLdnvpIJtL1FbpgainzoHFBVFZI6QfUqYg1QrE46k8Ckjolte6Tx8rUkuME4sWGXxGVWciERm6wKmUV9c653GB0UBDu@ZVQJAVNNOWg6F2WOt5WxeWHhgX1SytRxElRjqzktBLt@L1EbV9Yrkp1jLjA6hZWFADcWJnsobipTKilbMRpNLXWfYBx5gZvCxXmQfDbL8vIeiBMGuUBNna0T6jeamNkdUsRYMMcbnMBWX6dRdlf2NsYYF@hGa8WKSw5Yrxg2oTr5kic8xLA4aiAXPNzFde8N4EtNHO6BpzR@s3o2r0O9TacJ9cbnTqi36cD/7VBvgxnOwjSeYQw4nT7g7D7tdZMjuDzjoq06VB1vaxrqEdQHA8wi/Sx1901aAn29QtjndBCUoKB03XeFBxP5qLei7CqllzIrQVGGfMEU74G7ppOKvL57Y5jhEMghLDfCYVHGC5ZmpTgREJ2GY9yWCibLcsoumK/PXHLPQZu7EM9PwV8PoZ4P4DBdkxxmOAzfxjlsS8fMgsssl4sS28f/6sbqbSjZScgK@DY63gAXgPrrDMV7oUjrrLKeMP2ITguCB/eIhKxYeGViM3j/zEjoGxAuBasQaZhoWPD0F0MP2h@Sv/@hEXhzAR4xafh4oQCdpGMojqrbz/BiD0c1jMQRtwW5z3ym4WElmKzZeH@LgQcV2HTXCx6q4JmQqDvPJNjtO0G6IqdmBiF2lqVVHarTERMD7vO2LBPsdmvTL4y@R5qkimLN9553VjdedUVg7QtAMI05BIoHmlIVly1ABIRrIP3LRoBUWfYfp0lqgAYkRuuTuCgznPGq/vW39a/f61@T@fWhINhJLnaQ6z7z8IgISzUfOMyRJ4bYzE9MugUK/lrMUuC/hfkMILxdunjgDN6rpuvMV00HMhp48wheZKL6Jp7FpGuv7MFzJm5trBf13m/d6us5m1pMjg2ubPy2xliftdtOrC6q/Ko6IUku2MtbmKW2fG8yeP6gLDxpX3mpPErosC1FVx7nZFi35yDR9xhqswTBc59ibq6hE4tTeQiA8FpcXV2pVyZ5LXTf9@hKavrn@TORjx2fDe5xqtBv7lyt/OXYhDSb5jtPZ0Scui16AV8VvYYtL2nV@PIeq@MaYrpvACb9LHxzr4LYD37oZGIDOLI27OpiVrrAtXVvtm5ov@xXMXTHLIjOFcIOyzvAzZ7Nl7jypGn4a4Ewwl/F933V9@H5rryUFu88cXWsH9VhgUqfQjnuQdygkNFjku2tr1ravgMXq/ZEfd1DL/cHu3n9bv8OckVTNdfEBoordRXZzuo68WHUNJDyw6ghU/WGxW/@cPGgwOsvoE8vBNsO78hrD4DJbt7HypdSZnTo0r6DGzMcl3xsVE7Ovp3yORgxebZeNdctjxzhTZJFxJs0iim9j7iF7q/OnqbFKkbf6/Rmc30ZW4dyaj0VK9lXAdhKn1@efnH9SrcW2pvHBd4mi1pJmuG9z3mOS2zoSkMJyf4oirJXccQzNsuzJXsJf1@EWVmqdAMHYvB7UiICUEGyOcgg1Czr9dxyEZTCESYOYai2FQZLmkyzGU0ThTiDodZDFkHRgH8JIG4XQJAm6Y@4taGqbhnc4P0jNywIQy7Peuit0ger@Ih0YnE41xWfivgYvIoEwxFQ2eJRBX9hnH25Lle4RQkeqcIHoM/gnelYGDddYx38Ogj3aAgDAmD2ZYYcoTIBumjg3Ef/7tmb@@TnPaNDbcpFti7Ijh9AcFekg2CiYE7BLTLqz4K/N2zMV7sZp9IsfIKuQ2N9suNEQtolgotJ1VnXw85ayDHnETVVQZ/2pI91T5uWqgoZNc2xLwIKu12DuS25GD5g1IRMJQ/uOBLEJErFJAowyYdhswmvg9bmZ8JPyJQKy9fBZSCExMllFkd3tLutTTidtbrZlSJuBWcriy2Nxt9Vo/kIynT58TYhW0zOxCd4FE7utnhrKak7Qmw6XvCpxka8P8tSd9rRpze1h1iEQgkvDh7qtCqtHZwpVWP0d9YKAgZRnJAWCdMtTCIDnLqpyCliR3WLOyrFmQ6Ir4XiLMOh1/ET5El7OyTdZ7QZbtvmFWwZx57CTGBVdbpkL/vO2GrfbV6UwiVaxYLzkvXvTel@VqqNGXQxU8C2YdkrWaynsvAdcbkUpxOZcrpzAdj27nAxMbho9twBPwvjgCzmkE@zDNACoYnWz3D2apWy2Rmz@/aXzXsWOiC13lUzDS0/k5ejdwt8BgrHJdTy2zqqoylxgmJDOesVuIqT5AVd4tDJl25kjOII84EcwUQat4M3sbxVIuBT9Nb0VWiyIe/hPT6KTDFIx5I3IPUaPgxeXtVSGbv36Z/2PPC68r5V8UtnWxmrEjp9GBVrTc5GWKsWWhUazXY@tDPbcc2dAN7XvQhevK/G7N1Xg6M/iFCnaMz6zu1yInALxBfgEIIyzMsrzsE8nqYgwDbdSWG2uiERselPEuuQ55CB6FP7DPq3stBIaEeaSaza/7ZJmBR8NTn714pKwaCPACeVSWcCx8@7br7YFE/OPu4ntHgL4Tdtju4FTsD8zY7SbY2QdEVuBdo9Jsn8FcqSaqli6M434rraP2xhpPZJ/erC6@raYqspXdIlhH1NBPlaK3NdunTvddnHSWcdKMWVMsuSMl7V4q5K2JRmu@XdhqQbutxHETv5ilZVvLT1pTVvL5QJutzq@LjqdaptIDaFVf10cVE1dsWlc23AHyVoLnNOzgQL9FRukDBghHNUXdOsjGexmBSKvcTZ3gOpORxY3NhXRxcMHnU9kGcvlvH3GVhyBYKJOwS7xLiDoY/iS3QE9GApv6pPUwyhlWDcBUDheqoeWgGsHIhXCvke4XtJ03IdZSng1wfI0@uuwXwQjWdJMBdqw4CitQcd7X3oiJU0IknecZXHYImhqTkFi54O4FriFiU8eh0MOwymabQXOpqrtdSIAHeRQYZMt2Oku8HNMlr@KbldXgZz1NwLdipOIL83UACPLZvfmcTtArif8oh1gqxHwrH7xUTY9buORo2yGgP3XsK8esImtS0xqXNhjHb120RdD5gVo8o@dXYRz9OgXIP2ANqMXP2tNlxtjcmhO7/wtjRx@9eClN9Ndwt9FKqdgv7yFtQAY0JY9@qZoYCTzhkkIHMEGJOBAQ8jLJhnA0eEDKJRXRVltiNk@pdXGb5taMcx7m7t6mcbF00hmH0ulPpO/3U4pxiy4tQ0xi6UAmjNIpzRu1CqEZ7B7mZGdKRr0TaognUJNtIBkXVfASm6t7ZtIxP9bAzDagWnF5ZW5e4GdnQueoJRHW9sDehtEJT3eYh9gi0NqPrAxAZC3BUDE31SAjz9yG4uH2qznd66vmn/G6R23XSk733PUbv@Ify89708aheK3t4oervvjdLf@9qonZTc/8ooffjGqC03RA6KyV3XSv7YS1HG39dSlPnzUtSOpSjr56Won/5SFEjcb3kaDS9EDV6PvSXQr7vu3Qu1X4r7s3pWeZVO9lCVp4nsm5atIGG2LHWDjYTwSUkSgx0lr6PW7S3nSFZV0XJIu25MkMByjvGUItSwxqxzRxbYSohHZYhWaQXn3QNa6/LrFDSyOEHdvZsDzC1yBTUbYqt7t7adFtEmrWJ5pu6afcq2Gse62BD1ZKHRyLoqr9CHC9Z73@KYr3IKpaYFilxKMBo3dl2NXIM4AFNEgAI/pMY@kHuByp0JqOuw2TDjJeT1ijWPCl183g7e@kZE/52LLN1YvIr40MMFSBS8LB5xl@Gd5Pnk0t21I0z7gPvWREjm@569y3RzQVFRdqJ4zNv/EvDBw9/271Y0jXFV/JA@HfKrNtCGwqWmc/QJpCDixFG27ahdIWn0yh@Y8wiDR7ud/Rjh1l09GNgn@/9x7TuomOAQ98GHX0GP/yAO78kHJt4MZi2MS8VZmKqT4A17C@eV@cSny@6MJ@ZenDG@l3/HYeADHIJO@zZ34LsSpJGCt4bvIYymWXSzL3f9mMqy@felLNs/K8s7lGXnZ2X5p68sm7vjtkYFSCVxcNVvcvYUY5doTXgdJMkNm2c47YEysMpWIi4ouI6X66U4KKi6vUrEEk3XsxnPVfbFDSXSDrQrjouT4UJEVokpZwGQOcY5wUsNf4oRSiVothxqLfEu2YCUEOi9S67u1ZJPLAqtvy9R6P4sCneIQu9nUfjTF4XWNr/BX/7tf/wqnRare30XvG9ojn@84iXuEVjWerJ5ZFk2G7iCu7a5ClypgXIvsNywmTEkbHEHbtud3uyvqHKIRVdp9slEYRNfVAt2o8s95omlnVju8HKPgvupoGuMjUWfVnDd3h7c6tyDQZvfex@b3/vZ5v/Z5v/Z5v/Z5v/Z5v@JKLr235ei6/@s6O5QdHXtZ033p6/p2h/N6Ic5AVRRYC8wvWd4PAXZ5Jv7kuRGJCb393w@mUz@Hw) (Input doesn't contain the entire HTML content, because the TIO URL would extend 65k+ characters and be too big to post, haha.. xD)

**Reading from the API: <s>46</s> 42 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)**

```
•3X&•’¸¸.Â‚‹º.ŒŒ/…é/ÿ?€¼=ƒËŠˆ’žYì.w'š‹¡Åsþ
```

No direct TIO, since the `.w` builtin (to access a website) is disabled on TIO. But:

```
•3X&•’¸¸.Â‚‹º.ŒŒ/…é/ÿ?€¼=ƒËŠˆ’žYì
```

[Try this part online to see the generation of the API-URL.](https://tio.run/##AUoAtf9vc2FiaWX//@KAojNYJuKAouKAmcK4wrguw4LigJrigLnCui7FksWSL@KApsOpL8O/P@KCrMK8PcaSw4vFoMuG4oCZxb5Zw6z//w)

```
'š‹¡Åsþ
```

[Try this part online to see the extraction of the amount of views from the JSON.](https://tio.run/##lVFLjhMxEL1KVAvYdKc/k5BMSyOWsEVCbBCyiu6KU5puu8eunkyIIrHhIHMMNiwYcREuEmxnIsESLyzX5z3Xe2U9fmY6nV7@evz99fvPx6dv/unH6XQAFho8NB8PIKjjA1rbUa5tv4EMvGB7m9NDu0WjKceR4VMGdmfIQXMAR@MkKGwNNNWyWmUweXKKO2jq62VdPseyHwma0K3ZCznqAvPo7IZ7UjygjsWtyOibouB5@nPOg57cvLVDcVe9afV8NPq1v6nq9Qt9UwV8x37sca8MDhHOX3o2IR3u27/YopYo5Ux60ZFo42S@SGMWZ/QxA/YKjd@lGRtxE2Vwz7RTrZ2MBI2LDM71S6YOHrXWUXr16EVhK3zPslcdCkVb1qtyUS9W6wxaR8msf0plvX6Vwd1EPpWSd@XV8rr8HzEXeBCUsIVs2eeXbL5Fn0cdPjgkLH107H3omL177pi9RT9T8cw@pL5jWHNAqSFp22DvKQ5pBdWAD9BcleUldjQgGzY6Lf34Bw)

**Explanation:**

```python
’ƒËŠˆ.Â‚‹º.ŒŒ/q/’
              # Push dictionary string "codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/"
 žY           # Push builtin "https://"
   ì          # And prepend it in front of the url
    •3X&•     # Push compressed integer 203590 (the id of this question)
         «    # Append it to the url
          .w  # Access this URL and read its contents
'Ž‡          '# Push dictionary string "wed"
   ¡          # Split the HTML on this word
    1è        # Get the second item (at index 1)
              #  (i.e. ` 119 times">\n                    <span class="fc-light mr2">Vie`)
      þ       # Only leave the digits (i.e. 1992)
       ¨      # And remove the last digit (2), that was part of the class
              # (after which it is output implicitly as result)

•3X&•         # Push compressed integer 203590 (the id of this question)
 ’¸¸.Â‚‹º.ŒŒ/…é/ÿ?€¼=ƒËŠˆ’
              # Push dictionary string "api.stackexchange.com/questions/ÿ?site=codegolf",
              # where the `ÿ` is automatically filled with this integer
  žY          # Push builtin "https://"
    ì         # And prepend it in front of the url
     .w       # Access this URL and read its contents
'š‹          '# Push dictionary string "count"
   ¡          # Split the JSON on this word:
              #  (i.e. `...,"view_count":14,"answer_count":2,...` will be split to
              #   [`...,"view_`, `":14,"answer_`, `":2,...`])
    Ås        # Pop and only leave the middle item (i.e. `":14,"answer_`)
      þ       # Pop and only leave its digits (i.e. 14)
              # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to use the dictionary?* and *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `’ƒËŠˆ.Â‚‹º.ŒŒ/q/’` is `"codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/"`; `•3X&•` is `203590`; `'Ž‡` is `"wed"`; `’¸¸.Â‚‹º.ŒŒ/…é/ÿ?€¼=ƒËŠˆ’` is `"api.stackexchange.com/questions/ÿ?site=codegolf"`; and `'š‹` is `"count"`.

Comment: Does it actually need the `https://` schema on the url with `.w`? Don't have 05AB1E installed on this machine

Comment: Is there anything I need to configure to run it locally? when I try to run it the `.w` returns the string unchanged

Comment: @ExpiredData I think it indeed does need it, although I'm not sure. I've only installed 05AB1E locally for the first time a month ago when TIO was having issues for 2 days straight. Without the `https://` it doesn't return anything, but it seems it also doesn't seem to work with for some reason.. :/ If I access a website like google (i.e. `"www.google.com".w`) it reads it HTML-contents just fine, but if I use `"https://api.stackexchange.com/questions/203590?site=codegolf"=.w,` it seems there is some kind of encoding issue.. :S [Here is the output.](https://i.postimg.cc/qM3mPDPr/Untitled.png)

Comment: Unfortunately I only ever programmed once in Elixir, so I'm not entirely sure why normal HTML websites are read fine, but that JSON api url is having encoding issues.. In the `get_url` method it uses `HTTPoison.get!(url).body` to get the website contents (and the `url` is already casted to a string earlier).

Comment: Does it work better if you just directly get this question and parse view count from that?

Comment: 37 bytes: `•3X&•’ƒËŠˆ.Â‚‹º.ŒŒ/…é/ÿ’žYì.w'Ž‡¡¦¬þ¨`

Comment: 36 by using q instead of `…é`

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (browser), <s>129</s> <s>121</s> <s>129</s> 117 bytes

-12 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen, Command Master!

```js
await fetch`//api.stackexchange.com/questions/203590?site=codegolf`.then(x=>x.json()).then(x=>x.items[0].view_count)
```

### Another version, not using await (<s>136</s> <s>128</s> 136 bytes):

```js
fetch('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/203590?site=codegolf').then(x=>x.json()).then(x=>console.log(x.items[0].view_count))
```

Comment: I think you can save bytes by removing the `2.2/` in the API-URL.

Comment: You can also save 3 bytes by replacing https:// with http: (note this won't work in chrome or most other browsers if you loaded the page via https in the first place)

Comment: 106 bytes - `(await(await fetch\`http:api.stackexchange.com/questions/203590?site=codegolf\`).json()).items[0].view_count`

Comment: You can drop the `https:`, and only use `//api...```

Comment: also 111 bytes by directly using the StackExchange site: `await fetch('//codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/203590').then(x=>x.text()).then(x=>x.split('wed')[1].split(' ')[1])`

Comment: 96 by using the question directly and @ExpiredData's golf: ```(await(await fetch`//codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/203590`).text()).split('wed')[1].split(' ')[1]```

Comment: if [you can assume it's run from a specific domain](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13621/can-js-answers-require-the-code-to-be-run-at-a-certain-domain) you can ```(await(await fetch`/q/203590`).text()).split('wed')[1].split(' ')[1]``` for 68 bytes

Comment: You can save a few of bytes on @commandmaster 's 68 by using `.split\` \`` instead of `.split(' ')` and `.split\`wed\`` instead of `.split('wed')`

Comment: Also on phone so can't test but you may be able to do `parseInt(await...split\`wed\`[1])` instead of the `.split\` \`[1]` saving 3 bytes on top

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, <s>99</s> 95 bytes

```
=Mid(Index(ImportData("https://api.stackexchange.com/questions/203590?site=codegolf"),10),12,99
```

Sheets will add the trailing parentheses automatically.

`ImportData` will treat the result as a CSV and split the text into columns.
`Index(~,10)` pulls the 10th entry from that split result.
`Mid(~,12,99)` starts at the 12th character and pulls up to the next 99.

So long as the view count doesn't get to 10^99, this will work fine.

Here's a screenshot showing the three steps:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>125</s> 117 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to Kaddath*

Using only the standard library, unlike the other python answer.

```py
from urllib import*
x=urlopen("http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/203590").read()
print x[x.find("wed"):].split()[1]
```

## Python 3, <s>149</s> 142 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to Kaddath*

```py
from urllib.request import*
x=urlopen("http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/203590").read().decode("utf-8")
print(x[x.find("wed"):].split()[1])
```

Comment: Do you know that the trailing `/70761` is your user id to attribute the link share to you when someone clicks it (for badge I think), but it can be removed from the URL?

Answer (score 1):

### sh, 96 bytes

```
wget -qO- http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203590|sed -n 's/.*\(V.*mes\).*/\1/p;540q'
```

This assumes the presence of `wget` and `sed`. We can save 5 bytes (the `;540q` part) if we can assume there's no more match of `V.*mes` on the page -- as of this writing, there isn't, but that may not be true after more submissions. This also assumes the first part of the page is fairly static, and the `Viewed XXX times` sentence appears uniquely before line 540 (which it currently does).

### sh, 101 bytes

```
wget -qO- http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203590|sed -n 's/.*\(V.*mes\).*/\1/p;/V.*mes/q
```

Similar to the above, but this variation does not depend on which line the `Viewed XXX times` appears -- it terminates after the finding the first one.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) with `requests`, 113 bytes

```python
from requests import*
t=get('http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/203590').text
print t[t.find('wed'):].split()[1]
```

A pair of `()` is needed for Python 3 (114 bytes).

Comment: You might want to mention that you're using a 3rd party library(requests)

Comment: Done, thanks. @SuperStormer

Comment: polyglot with python3

Comment: oh the print format doesn't work in python3

Comment: so for python3 it's +1, with `()`

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>96</s> 89 bytes

```php
<?=split(' ',strstr(join(file('http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/203590')),'wed '))[1];
```

Inspired by @newbie's answer. I think I can do better, still a first try. I strangely only got malformed characters from the JSON api :/

EDIT gained 7 bytes using `split` and `strstr` instead of `preg_match`

Answer (score 0):

## Bash + common tools, 67

```bash
lynx -dump codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/203590|grep -Po 'wed \K\d+'
```

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 43 bytes

T-SQL executed directly against the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/1227273/viewcount-of-a-specific-question-id):

```sql
SELECT ViewCount FROM Posts WHERE Id=203590
```

Based on my answer [to this similar question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143116/70172).